Indirect Addressing P16F877
Suppose i have two numbers n1 & n2, one in bank 0 and the other in bank 2, i want to do a sum operation on them using the indirect addressing approach, here is the code from my lecture which is wrong after tested in mplab 8.92, i need someone to correct it thanks:
nbr1 equ 0xA0
nbr2 equ 0x121
som12 equ 0x1A2
; les instructions ci-dessus utilisant la directive (equ) peuvent être remplacées par la directive cblock :
; cblock 0x20
; nbr1, nbr2, som12
; endc
w equ 0
f equ 1
; la macro suivante (bank0) est un sous-programme qui permet de configurer STATUS pour pointer sur bank#0

; ------------- Programme principal ---------------------------------------
org 0x00 ; définir la position initiale dans la mémoire programme
debut
    ;nbr1:
    CLRF STATUS;IRP = 0
    movlw 0xA0
    movwf FSR  ;FSR=0xA0
    movlw 0xFF ; transférer la valeur (0x0A) dans l'accumulateur w
    movwf INDF ; transférer le contenu de W à l'adresse du nbr1

    ;nbr2:
    bsf STATUS, IRP;IRP = 1
    movlw 0x21
    movwf FSR ;FSR=0x21
    movlw 0x01 ; transférer la valeur (0x0A) dans l'accumulateur w
    movwf INDF
    
    ;Charger addresse de nbr1 dans FSR
    bcf STATUS, IRP;IRP = 0
    movlw 0xA0
    movwf FSR ;FSR=0xA0
    addwf INDF,w ; additionner w à la variable nbr2
    
    bsf STATUS, IRP;IRP = 1
    movlw 0xA2
    movwf FSR ;FSR=0xA2
    movwf INDF ; stoker le résultat de la somme à partir de w sur la variable som12
    goto debut ; réexécuter la boucle depuis le label « début »
    end```


I tried to rewrite the code but unfortunately i dont know much, im used to the x86 assembly so using PICs are abit difficult


Maybe you can tell how you came to the conclusion that this code is wrong?

@StefanWyss look at the third block of code last instruction "addwf INDF, w" , the wreg is already filled with A0h ,     thus addwf indf, w will load w with the content of the INDF with is 0xFF and adding it to 0xA0, which will give out 19F, the whole code is dumb, the professor spat that code randomly. you can verify that using mplab

Would you mind to translate your comments to English, please? And while you're at it, let the code part end before your last statement.
